# Filter array of objects in which not all keys are present - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
[
  {
      "id": "1",
      "LB1": "Kod produktu: PMPSB216IN80",
      "Type": "Figurki"
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "Type": "Głowa Do Stylizacji"
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "LB1": "Kod produktu: 97834",
      "Type": "Pluszak"
  },
]
```

Than I'm defining a string: '97834'

And I want to filter the array based on LB1 value:

```
filteredProducts = productList.filter(product => product.LB1.replace('Kod produktu: ', '').toLowerCase() === this.props.searchTerm.toLowerCase());
```

However as you can see above - not all objects contain this LB1 - and the function is throwing an error:

```
Test.js:101 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
```

Comment: And the problem is? Just add an `if` that tests for the existence of that property before replacing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a condition, in your filter function, that checks for the existance of that property. Here, i'm using the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator, to validate just that.

```js
const productList = [
  {
      "id": "1",
      "LB1": "Kod produktu: PMPSB216IN80",
      "Type": "Figurki"
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "Type": "Głowa Do Stylizacji"
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "LB1": "Kod produktu: 97834",
      "Type": "Pluszak"
  },
]

const searchTerm = '97834' /*  this.props.searchTerm.toLowerCase() */;

const filteredProducts = productList.filter(product => 'LB1' in product && product.LB1.replace('Kod produktu: ', '').toLowerCase() === searchTerm );

console.log('output', filteredProducts);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if LB1 exists - if it doesn't, filter it out as if it didn't match your search term (here I'm using [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND):

```
filteredProducts = productList.filter(product => product.LB1 != null && product.LB1.replace('Kod produktu: ', '').toLowerCase() === this.props.searchTerm.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: And if `product.LB1 === 0`?

Comment: Fair point @Clive! It should read `product.LB1 != null` to check for null and undefined

Comment: If you wanna get technical (and let’s face it, we do here), that’s also not right. A value of `null` means the property is set. For robust code, use `typeof product.LB1 !== ‘undefined’` for that approach. Using `in` or optional chaining are arguably both more readable

Comment: Definitely see where you're coming from here. I'm curious, though, what would you say to the argument that merely checking for nullish here (even 0) would meet our requirement of filtering out objects that don't contain a string property for LB1?  Won't we get a TypeError that `replace` is not a function?

Comment: I guess we'd get that anyway if `product.LB1 === 1`, say, so moot point I suppose

Comment: Yeah I see your point but at the same time the OP only mentions _not all objects contain this LB1_. Nothing mentioned about objects with the property but with an undesired value